# Squeryl relation 1:N

Tags: mysql, scala, squeryl

I experienced some troubles with Squeryl ORM. Very basic functionality like select or insert rows without relations works fine, problems begin when I try to get data with relation 1:N in trivial scenario.
In test DB I create two tables Questions and Answers. One question can contain several answers. Here is tables creation SQL:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `questions`;
CREATE TABLE `questions` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `questions` (`id`, `nid`, `text`, `active`)
VALUES
(1,1,'test question',1),
(2,2,'second question',1);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `answers`;
CREATE TABLE `answers` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `question_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `qwerty` (`question_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `qwerty` FOREIGN KEY (`question_id`) REFERENCES `questions` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `answers` (`id`, `question_id`, `text`)
VALUES
(1,1,'test answer');
```

And here is Scala code with model classes:

```
class BaseEntity extends KeyedEntity[Long] { val id: Long = 0 }

class Question(var nid: Long, var text: String, 
      var active: Integer) extends BaseEntity {

    def this() = this(0, "", 1)
    lazy val Answers: List[Answer] = DataBase.answersToQuestion.left(this).toList
}

class Answer(var question_id: Long, var text: String) extends BaseEntity { 
    def this() = this(0, "")
    lazy val Question: Question = DataBase.answersToQuestion.right(this).head
}

object DataBase extends Schema {
    val questions = table[Question]("questions")
    val answers = table[Answer]("answers")
    val answersToQuestion = oneToManyRelation(questions, answers)
        .via((q, a) => q.id === a.question_id)

    on(answers)(a => declare( a.id is (autoIncremented) ))
    on(questions)(q => declare( q.id is (autoIncremented) ))
}
```

So on data selection I get full Question object but Answers is always null.

```
var question: Option[Question] = inTransaction { DataBase.questions.lookup(1L) }
//question.Answers is null !!
```

Can someone please look at is and tell me what is my mistake?

Comment: Are there any errors returned from SQL to your database connector?  You might want to start there.

Comment: No errors at all. Other fields retrieved successfully

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I just hope for another behavior or misconfigured ORM somehow, although I get null in debugger, but it is work fine this way for Answer class:

```
def getQuestion = inTransaction(Question.headOption)
```

And this way for Question:

```
def getAnswers = inTransaction(Answers.toList)
```

Hope this would be helpful for someone who is new to Squeryl and experienced the same problem as I do.

Don't mark question as answered so far cause maybe there is better solution.

Comment: All calls to the database need to happen within a transaction, so it makes sense that requesting the answers outside of one would not work - I am just surprised there was no error, as Squeryl would usually thrown one. 

In any case, if you removed the `lazy` it would probably also work for you, although it would populate that on retrieval. Alternately you could also add inTransaction in the original object - like: `lazy val Answers: List[Answer] = inTransaction { DataBase.answersToQuestion.left(this).toList }`. `inTransaction` will join an existing transaction if one exists, so nesting is fine